# How to SetText Some Strings Repetitive Like Animation-List?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have 4 Strings that I want to show them in 1 `textview` every 3 seconds and make it repeat.

like `animation-list` that show some `.png` file.

to be clear, I Want To Do This:

```
while(true){

    tv.SetText("Text1");
    //delay for 3 second
    tv.SetText("Text2");
    //delay for 3 second
    tv.SetText("Text3");
    //delay for 3 second
    tv.SetText("Text4");
    //delay for 3 second

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private int count = 1;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(count+"");
                count++;
                if (count > 3) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                } else {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);    
                }
            }
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to achieve this you can:

1. create a handler.
2. use the handler sendMessageDelayed function with the delay you want.
3. Override handleMessage function, and update the text view when the message arrives.

/***//

```
 private static final int MSG_UPDATE_STRING = 1;
 private static final int STRING_REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 3000;
 private static StaticHandler mHandler = new StaticHandler();
 //StaticHandler is an inner class. write it inside your activity class.
 public static class StaticHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_UPDATE_STRING:
             //update textview here
             ...
             //resend message so it will continue to refresh
             mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_DATA_PACKET_TIMEOUT,STRING_REFRESH_INTERVAL_MILLIS );
             break;
        }
    }
}
```